# Regular Expression to convert String upper case to lower case in php

Tags: php, regex

Here is my problem

In a single PHP file, demonstrate a regular expression to convert `"123 Tree Street, Connecticut"` into `"123_tree_street_connecticut"`.

I have successfully replace spaces and comma with `_`, but unable to change character case using Regular expression in php.

what i have did is

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/(,\s|\s)/', '_', '123 Tree Street, Connecticut');
?>
```

It replaces spaces and commas with `_` but not able to change it's case.

Can any one guide me to how it is done Using php and regular expression only.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have to do it with regular expressions?

Comment: This is not a good problem to be solved with regular expressions, use `strtolower` instead.

Comment: Sounds like homework. If it is, it would be polite to say so and show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 5):

Since the regex replacement will use the `strtolower()` function, I see no reason to not just [do it all](http://www.ideone.com/F7Z43) with simple string functions:

```
<?php

$str = '123 Tree Street, Connecticut';
$str = strtolower(str_replace(array(', ', ' '), '_', $str));

print_r($str);

?>
```

If `strtolower()` is not "allowed", you could perform a shift based on the character table distance between upper- and lowercase letters. It's not pretty but it [seems to work](http://www.ideone.com/Xwk5g) (in this specific case):

```
<?php

function shiftToLower($char) {
    $ord = ord($char);
    return $ord < 65 || $ord > 90 ? '_' : chr($ord + 32); // 65 = A, 90 = Z
}

$str = '123 Tree Street, Connecticut';
$str = preg_replace('/([, ]+|[A-Z])/e', "shiftToLower('\\1')", $str);

print_r($str);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Input :

```
<?php
// either use this //
echo str_replace(',', '', str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower("123 Tree Street, Connecticut")));

echo "\n";

// or use this //
echo str_replace(array(', ', ' '), '_', strtolower("123 Tree Street, Connecticut"));
?>
```

Output :

```
123_tree_street_connecticut
123_tree_street_connecticut
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is any built-in regex solution for to change the case. But I think you can do it by hands by writing a new regex for every character.

Converting to upper case example:

```
$new_string = preg_replace(
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ....),
    array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ....),
    $string
);
```

I think you got the point.