# Regular expression for changing URL's to lower case

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on several websites powered by PHP and MySQL and want to change all my URL's to lower case and replace underscores with dashes. So the URL mysite/Topics/Tic_Tac_Toe would change to mysite/topics/tic-tac-toe.

I wonder if anyone could suggest a regular expression that would automatically do the job. If doing two things at once is too much, then I'd like to at least be able to change everything to lower case. I can probably find another way to replace the underscores.

The links I want to change are all local links, and most take one of these forms:

```
<a href="/Topics/New_York title="New York">New York</a>
<a href=<?php echo $GS_URL; >/Topics/New_York" title="New York/New York</a>
<a href='.$GS_URL.'/Topics/New_York" title="New York/New York</a>
```

However, the section name varies, including Topics, Reference, World, etc. The value $GS_URL (which represents a domain name) also varies, including $GW_URL, $GZ_URL and $PX_URL. So I think it would be safe to simply use a regex that affects every LOCAL link; i.e. every link that does not begin with http://. Also, I don't want it to affect links to images, including the following:

```
<a href="'.$PX_URL.'/images/Maps/US/Red_Blue_States.png" title="map">map</a>
```

If what I'm asking is too complex, a good alternative would be a regex that affects every URL that begins with /Topics or /topics (I've already changed /Topics to /topics in some files), like this...

```
<a href="/Topics/New_York title="New York">New York</a>
```

I could then do a search-and-replace operation, then change it from /Topics to /World - /world, then /Reference - /reference, etc.

Also, I should mention that the software I'm using to do these search-and-replace operations are Dreamweaver and TextWrangler.

Comment: Regex is probably not a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, what you're looking for is a regex usable in your editing software, and the only relevance of PHP is that the text files you're working with happen to be PHP source code?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I probably shouldn't have even mentioned PHP. ;) I just do most of my work in PHP, though I've also learned to use TextWrangler for search-and-replace operations. I think it's regex function is a little different than Dreamweaver's, though I don't really understand the details.

Comment: I should add that I am aware of PHP's strtolower function, as described @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383572/regular-expression-to-convert-string-upper-case-to-lower-case-in-php?rq=1 However, that won't work because much of my text is in static includes, not a database. Also, I'd have to figure out how to apply the strtolower function to local links only (and not to image links).

Answer (score 0):

Well if youre using LINUX environment for your websites, and if your urls are STATIC driven, there is no solution for your problem I'm afraid, but to change data/files/includes/calls, everything by yourself - manually. On LINUX platform changing Caps on urls will affect core and `.html` files all together (what will be hard to trace if youre working on a VPS with Windows platform during development), then probably friendly urls function will suffer.. there may be a real mess online, when site lands on LINUX.

Anyway, if you want to change urls ONLY (what youre asking), you can use string splits and play around with this code. Simply c/p into your index.php and you will know what to do with it later if given PHP code structure will be helpful.

```
    //choice of img types for uries not to be changed..
$nochange = array('.png','.gif','.jpg');


    $uri = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : '';

    //for now ignore server uri, lets set some possible, problematic uri (uncoment after youre done)
    $uri = 'www.extra.mysite/Topics/png/BomBastic/Tic_Tac_Toe-Candies/hoT_GIRls-OnA_Va-CAT-Ion.jpg';

    $urlvariables = (substr($uri, 0, 1) == '/') ? substr($uri, 1) : $uri;
    $variables = explode('/', $uri);
    $ec = (count($variables)-1);

     if(preg_match('#(\.png$)|(\.jpg$)|(.gif$)#', $variables[count($variables)-1]))
      {
        $last = $variables[count($variables)-1];

        for($i = 0; $i < $ec; $i++)
        {
        $var .= $variables[$i] . '/';
        }
       $var = str_replace('_', '-', $var);
       $var = strtolower($var) . $last;

      }
      else
      {
        $var = str_replace('_', '-', $var);
        $var = strtolower($uri);
      }

      //final echo
      echo $var;
```

Good luck!

Comment: @David Blomstrom Hey Dav id, just been wondering did you find any help from this answer..? Is it okay?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a chance to get back to work until today. I think I should have explained more clearly that, though my site is database-driven, these particular files are includes that include internal links. I want to put most of this content into a database, but first I want to change all the URL's to lower case. So I'm just looking for a convenient way to modify the URL's with Dreamweaver, TextWrangler or whatever before I put everything into a database.

Comment: However, I think I can still use your script anyway. When I publish my upgrade, I can use it to correct any URL's that didn't get fixed for some reason until I get a chance to finish the job. Thanks. ;)